# Windows Phone TextBox barely clickable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, clickable

I have a TextBox in my Windows Phone application. It seems only the upper half of the TextBox is clickable to edit the Text. I need the whole TextBox to be clickable.

Why is this?

```
<Grid x:Name="FolderNameGrid">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPostbox.LabelToUpper}"
               Style="{StaticResource PageTitleTextBlockStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding IsInSearchMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=!}" />

    <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox"
             Margin="20,10,20,10"
             KeyDown="SearchTextBox_OnKeyDown"
             TextChanged="SearchTextBox_OnTextChanged"
             GotFocus="SearchTextBox_GotFocus"
             PlaceholderText="{Binding TextSource, Converter={StaticResource Language}, ConverterParameter=Module-Messages-Search, FallbackValue=Module-Messages-Search}"
             Visibility="{Binding IsInSearchMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You surely have another control that overlapse the TextBox, or something like that. We will need to have the ful XAML page to help you.

Comment: It is inside a Grid. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding RowDefinitions to your grid. The 2 controls are overlapping now.

e.g.

```
<Grid x:Name="FolderNameGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition />
       <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPostbox.LabelToUpper}"
               Style="{StaticResource PageTitleTextBlockStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding IsInSearchMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=!}" />

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             x:Name="SearchTextBox"
             Margin="20,10,20,10"
             KeyDown="SearchTextBox_OnKeyDown"
             TextChanged="SearchTextBox_OnTextChanged"
             GotFocus="SearchTextBox_GotFocus"
             PlaceholderText="{Binding TextSource, Converter={StaticResource Language}, ConverterParameter=Module-Messages-Search, FallbackValue=Module-Messages-Search}"
             Visibility="{Binding IsInSearchMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```